# Openlayers PanZoomBar won't work

Tags: openlayers-2

In which cases PanZoomBar in Openlayers won't work, and what could be the solution? I'm using Openlayers 2.13, and sometimes, i cannot scroll to zoom in/out, only by clicking can be zoomed.

Comment: You will need to post some code for anyone to have a chance of answering that -- jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: Well, it's huge project. One page contains several js files, in one js file are called WMS and WFS layers etc. It needs a lot of code to be post. That's why i asked generalized question.

Comment: Well, generally, if controls don't work in OpenLayers, it is it because of a Javascript error elsewhere -- is there nothing in dev tools indicating an error.

Comment: I'm using Firebug, can't find it. I think it's because of calling layers, there is something wrong with it, and i can't see it. Something blocks PanZoomBar to work properly, cause in js file where i call layers, i call OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(). Somewhere works fine, on other pages don't.

Answer (score 1):

To test you can add OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar() yourself by code then remove it and re add it by code putting in a javascript event :

```
var control_pan = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();

map.addControl(control_pan);

map.removeControl(control_pan);
```

But the simplest thing would be a public link to your page.